# Is there a git gui tool to check and commit changes in cloud9 editor?

Tags: git, user-interface, cloud9-ide

Is there a git gui tool to check and commit changes in cloud9 editor ?
Do I have to use git status and git diff ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try ungit: http://root-project.org/2014/07/09/work/ungit-on-cloud9/
Note that you can only run on port 8080.